# Playing a video between two times in Android

Tags: android, video

I need for an android app the ability to play a video from a time t1 to an other time t2. Basically, this video is a kind of "sprite" in my app (it's an .mp4 video h264 baseline encoded).

So, I tried the following. A button "next" plays the video between t1 and t2. To check if the video has arrived to t2, I use an handler with a postDelayed call every 20 ms. If the video current position is bigger than t2, I stop the video. Otherwise, I check again in 20ms.

But it does not work. For a reason I don't understand, the video current position I read in postDelayed goes suddenly from a time to a few seconds later. On my screen, the video plays normally.

Some code:

```
// MainActivity
// setting up the video
vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVid);
vidView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/myvid"));    

// wiring up Bt next    
Button nextBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
nextBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          playVideo();
     }
});
```

And the playVideo method:

```
private void playVideo() {

    // t1 and t2 are defined within MainActivity class
t1 = (int) (Math.random() * (80000));
t2 = t1 + (int) (Math.random() * (5000));

    // we start at t1
vidView.seekTo(t1);

// We check video position in 20 ms
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

      int currentTime = vidView.getCurrentPosition();

         Log.i("currentTime", String.valueOf(currentTime));
         Log.i("T2", String.valueOf(t2));

      // Ok, we can pause the video
      if(currentTime > t2 - 20) {

          vidView.pause();          

       } 
       // We check again in 20ms
       else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20);
       }
    }
 }, 20);
 vidView.start();

}
```

The logCat gives me (in this example, T1 = 47286 and T2 = 51478)

```
10-14 11:31:56.603: I/currentTime(3359): 47286 // first call to postDelayed, fine
10-14 11:31:56.603: I/T2(3359): 51478

10-14 11:31:56.623: I/currentTime(3359): 47286 // second call to postDelayed, still ok
10-14 11:31:56.623: I/T2(3359): 51478

10-14 11:31:56.653: I/currentTime(3359): 50000 // What? How the video current time can already be 3 seconds later?
10-14 11:31:56.653: I/T2(3359): 51478
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly checking why don't you just set a handler to stop it at a specific later time? You don't need to check if it has "arrived" at T2 - you know when you want to stop it, so just schedule to stop it then.

```
Runnable stopVideoTask = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        vidView.pause();
    }
};

int t2 = (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
vidView.seekTo(t1);
vidView.start();
mHandler.postDelayed(stopVideoTask, t2);
```

The video will stop after `Math.random() * 5000` seconds of playing.

Comment: I want it to be as accurate as possible. The problem with your idea is that a video takes time to reach its seeking point and also to start playing. These times depend on the device and the video encoding. I figured doing a check every 20ms (not during all the video playback but rather in the last second of playback) would be more accurate.

Comment: Add an `onPreparedListener` to the video and only post the handler `onPrepared` - this will eliminate the start time problem. `getCurrentPosition` is not guaranteed to be accurate and certainly calling it every 20ms seems a bad idea to me.

Comment: I tried your idea but it still does not work as I would like it to. I used `MediaPlayer` + `SufaceView` to be able to post the handler on the `onSeekComplete` event. Basically it works, but it's not accurate enough: the video is paused with an error of time between 200 and 1500 ms.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. My only other advice is to see if the problem persists with a differently encoded video or create another timer to test the correct amount of time is elapsing (eg not relying on `getCurrentPosition` as your test).